# Amazon Product Advertising API - searching for multiple UPCs

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

Using the Amazon Product Advertising API I am searching for 2 different UPCs:

```
 // prepare the first ItemSearchRequest
 // prepare a second ItemSearchRequest
 ItemSearchRequest request1 = new ItemSearchRequest();
 request1.SearchIndex = "All";
 //request1.Keywords = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
 request1.Keywords="9120031340270";
 request1.ItemPage = "1";
 request1.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "OfferSummary" };


 ItemSearchRequest request2 = new ItemSearchRequest();
 request2.SearchIndex = "All";
 //request2.Keywords = table.Rows[i+1].ItemArray[0].ToString();
 request2.Keywords = "9120031340300";
 request2.ItemPage = "1";
 request2.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "OfferSummary" };

                
 // batch the two requests together
 ItemSearch itemSearch = new ItemSearch();
 itemSearch.Request = new ItemSearchRequest[] { request1,request2 };
 itemSearch.AWSAccessKeyId = accessKeyId;

 // issue the ItemSearch request
 ItemSearchResponse response = client.ItemSearch(itemSearch);


 foreach (var item in response.Items[0].Item)
 {
 
 }
 foreach (var item in response.Items[1].Item)
 {
 

 }
```

Is it possible to combine these two separate requests into one request and just have the first request return 2 items by setting `keywords = "9120031340256 and 9120031340270"`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Do I need to specifically search the UPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising/)
package.

```
PM> Install-Package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising
```

**Example**

```cs
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication("accesskey", "secretkey");
var client = new AmazonProductAdvertisingClient(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.US);
var result = await client.GetItemsAsync(new string[] { "B00BYPW00I", "B004MKNBJG" });
```

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the [API docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) I think you may want to use an ItemLookup if you want to get results for multiple UPCs.

```
ItemLookup itemLookup = new ItemLookup(){
    AssociateTag = "myaffiliatetag-20"
};
itemLookup.AWSAccessKeyId = MY_AWS_ID;

ItemLookupRequest itemLookupRequest = new ItemLookupRequest();
itemLookupRequest.IdTypeSpecified = true;
itemLookupRequest.IdType = ItemLookupRequestIdType.UPC;
itemLookupRequest.ItemId = new String[] { "9120031340300", "9120031340270" };
itemLookupRequest.ResponseGroup = new String[] { "OfferSummary" };
itemLookup.Request = new ItemLookupRequest[] { itemLookupRequest };

ItemLookupResponse response = client.ItemLookup(itemLookup);
foreach(var item in response.Items[0])
{
  //Do something...
  Console.WriteLine(item.ItemAttributes.Title);
}
```

That being said, if you *are not* working with lookups by some ID (UPC, ASIN, etc) your original code of doing batched keyword searches appears to be only way to make multiple keyword searches in a single request (that I could find..).  If doing keyword searches you could always make a ItemSearchRequest generator method to cut down on duplicate code when creating multiples.

Comment: thank you but this is not working for me. for some reason perhaps we are signing the request incorrectly?

Comment: I would post more details about any error you are getting with either method.

Comment: this is a great article if you're having trouble signing (which is now required) : http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/17/ - you'll need to download the sample project